# SQL Query INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN Want to select posts from specific categories in Wordpress but do NOT select those of another specific category

Tags: sql, wordpress, left-join, inner-join

Selecting specific categories works fine:

```
SELECT ID, post_content, post_title
FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.id
  AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (17,19)
```

Now adding the exception, to NOT select posts which are for example in category 17 AND in category 20, they should be excluded from the select query.

I tried this:

```
SELECT ID, post_content, post_title
FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (17,19)
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (20)
```

But it does not show any effect.
Anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Move the wp_term_relationships conditions from WHERE to ON.

Comment: Tried moving it to the ON part but this did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT wp.ID, wp.post_content, wp.post_title
FROM wp_posts wp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM  wp_term_relationships tr 
                  WHERE tr.object_id = wp.id AND
                        tr.term_taxonomy_id IN (17, 19)
                 );
```

This removes any relationships that have either 17 or 19.

Another approach is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT wp.ID, wp.post_content, wp.post_title
FROM wp_posts wp JOIN
     wp_term_relationships tr 
     ON tr.object_id = wp.id
GROUP BY wp.ID, wp.post_content, wp.post_title
HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN tr.term_taxonomy_id IN (17, 19) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Awesome!!! I used the second approach which works fine... I added some more WHERE conditions to narrow the SELECT down to select only: wp.post_type = 'post' and a special date condition: wp.post_date < '$daybefore' (24 hour old posts only). I use this SELECT in a php Script which runs through all posts on a wordpress news website. The Script basically adds a shortcode to the SELECTED posts. Thank you a lot, this was a great help!